# What are some fundamental issues computer science tries to address?

Tags: philosophy

I was wondering, if physics has the origins of the universe or the nature of space, time, and matter, biology has the existence of the cell and the origin of life, are there mysteries that computer science could seek to unravel?

This question does not concern the theories and technologies developed by computer science, but more existential, ontological issues.

Comment: Would you ask the same question for Chemistry, Math?

Comment: Why does there have to be a mystery and why is the structure of the cell mysterious?

Comment: Meta thread open [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/953/why-close-what-are-some-of-the-mysteries-computer-science-tries-to-answer).

Comment: The fundamental issue that computer science seeks to address is the nature of computation.

Comment: I've heard this response before... can you please provide a specific definition for "computation"? I've heard the phrase "Turing completeness" used in this definition. If so, could you please define this as well? I'm not sure answering this question by using the term "computation" is adequate because i clearly don't understand what "computational science" is...

Comment: P vs. NP problem is itself a huge mystery and yet to be solved.

Answer (score 5):

Computer science addresses the mystery of computation (but not computers): what is computable, what is not-computable, how difficult it is to solve certain problems, when are programs correct, how can programs be effectively written, what's the best way of solving problem X (for many Xs), ...

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit? What is the mystery of computation?

Comment: If it weren't a mystery, you wouldn't have to ask :)